# not show 500 error in dev console after catching exception

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

My environment is Angular 2 front and node as backend. I have a component class that is making calls to a DataService that calls node backend. When node backend returns 500 for the error cases, it s currently printing the whole uncaught exception message on the browser developer console. so, I added a catch like this:

```
let productPromise: Promise<void> = this.dataService.getProduct()
        .then((product: IProduct): void => {
            //
            //

        })
        .catch(function (data) {
            //TO implement
        });
```

With this, it does not print the big uncaught exception on the console, but it still shows:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/api/products 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

We will be deciding later on what exact messagge to display on the UI. But, at this time, we do not want to show the following 500 error in dev console:

```
GET http://localhost:9000/api/products 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: In Chrome, check the "Hide Network" checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers usually log the HTTP errors. We can hide them only by tweaking browser's settings.